# True and useful process detachment in Windows

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a distribution program that runs command lines at various intervals.  Think cron, here.  Ideally, this would be cross-platform, but cron already exists in *nix, so this is mainly for Windows.

Given the many issues of trying to spawn and keep a daemon-like perl script running robustly, my thought was to have the OS's scheduler kick off the script every minute and have the script determine which command lines are to be run and then do so.  Some of you can already see the issues...

The Windows Scheduler will not run a job if it's already running.  So, to run the cron-ish perl script, it will have to be finished in less than a minute, or else some scheduled command lines may be skipped.  For example, something run hourly that takes more than a minute will keep something from running that's scheduled for 1 minute past the hour.  For example, try a perl program that runs this command:

```
system 1,'perl -e "sleep 10"';
```

You'd think the program would return to the command prompt immediately with the "sleep 10" running in Windows' background... but nope, the parent script waits 10 seconds before exiting.

My current solution is to actually loop the program until all the commands finish... and each minute, re-enter the loop that reads the crontab-like input.  This is a nightmare for a variety of reasons, not the least of which is that my scheduler script becomes beholden to the commands it starts.

One might think forking the system call to run each command would work, but in Windows the parent script will not exit until the children are finished.  And for some odd reason, this is still the case even if the command line uses the Windows 'start' command.

I tried Win32::Process but that has some oddball limitations, mainly that it requires an explicit Windows program to be identified.  I wrote a wrapper around Win32::Process that ferrets out the program being run in a command line, finds it in the path (also looking for the type of program by using $ENV{PATHEXT}... for example, Win32::Process wouldn't accept 'notepad' so I have to determine that 'notepad.exe' is what it wants, and then find that in the path).  If the program isn't found, I assume the program is $ENV{COMSPEC} and add '/c'.  All of that works pretty well... until...

If I use this approach, every time some commands come up in the schedule, windows start popping up on my screen.  That can really be a pain if you're typing an email and the window focus bounces around so you are typing into other windows all of a sudden.  Productivity killer!

Enter start.  Using START /MIN will start the new processes minimized, so they don't pop on top of whatever I am doing.  But START isn't a true program, so trying to find it for my Win32::Process wrapper then defaults it to $ENV{COMSPEC}.  All well and fine here... so a command such as "dosomething.pl arg1 arg2" can be re-tuned to "cmd /c start /MIN dosomething.pl arg1 arg2".  Which works great... until...

... I try a command like "domsomething.pl arg1 arg2 >out.txt".  Changing that to "cmd /c start /MIN dosomething.pl arg1 arg2 >out.txt" sends the output of start to out.txt... which is generally nothing (start is pretty quiet that way).

Additionally, my Win32::Process wrapper isn't savvy enough (if I avoid the cmd and start stuff) to know that a command such as "dosomething.pl arg1 arg2" needs to be "perl -S dosomething.pl arg1 arg2"... which then perl could be found as perl.exe in the path.  It's Windows that recognizes the .pl extension and runs perl.  Win32::Process doesn't ask Windows for such information, depending on me to figure it out on my own.  I imagine there is a Win32 module somewhere that could get this for me.  Anyone know if that is true?

So, here I am.  No 100% good way to detach a process... fork() and "system 1,$cmd" both keep the parent running until the children have finished.  Win32::Process is a nightmare to automatically try and gather everything it needs to work properly.

Has anyone skinned this cat?  Any suggestions?  Thanks tons, y'all.

Comment: Why not write that wrapper carefully and do as in mob's answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I skinned this cat, but my notes say the workflow is something like

```
use Win32::Process;
@cmd = (...);    # I think it's ok to begin with START or CMD
my $procObj;
Win32::Process::Create( $procObj, $cmd[0], join(' ',@cmd), 0,
                        &Win32::Process::DETACHED_PROCESS, "/" )
    or die "failed to create detached proc: ",
           Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
```

That `join(' ',@cmd)` is a trap if your command has spaces or other metacharacters, so let's just say that issue is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: $cmd[0] HAS to be a fully-path'ed executable for Win32::Process::Create to work.  So, a command like "something.pl arg1 arg2" will not run because something.pl is not a Windows executable (nor is it a complete explicit path to something.pl.  When run in system, a command line is passed to the OS, which looks up .pl, sees that it requires the perl executable, and reconstructs its own $cmd[0].  I have, since this post, tried to look into doing that lookup myself, using `ftype` and `assoc`.  It's a hodge-podge in there so it's not easy to parse out successfully for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I am at... does anyone have a better idea?

So, the command I want to run is in $cmdline, the code becomes:

```
my $pgm=$ENV{COMSPEC};
$cmdline='/c start /min cmd /c '.$cmdline;
my $flags=DETACHED_PROCESS;
Win32::Process::Create(my $ProcessObj,
    $pgm,
    $cmdline,
    0, # setting this to 1 will make this script wait on this process to end
    $flags,
    '.', # working dir
);
```

And then, if I want to capture output from a command, I have to "escape" the '>' and '&' characters thusly:

```
$cmdline='pl2 E:\\scripts\\PERLDO_Stuff\\Sums2.perldo ^>e:\\pl2.log 2^>^&1'
```

(Note: pl2.pl is a perl script in my PATH)

Note how the `>file.ext` is now `^>file.ext` and the `2>&1` becomes `2^>^&1`.  This is, so far, the only way I've gotten this to work.

Does anyone else have any other ideas on this?

Comment: The downside to this approach is that if I WANT to wait on the process and get the return exit code, I can't.  This is because the START returns almost immediately, so whatever is being START'ed is not the real process being watched.  OTOH, if I want to wait on the process, I can just use the `system` command.